# Trim NSNumber to 8 decimal places

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

i have an ios app that shows the latitude of your current location. i want to limit the number of digits in the latitude to 8 decimal points. I used NSNumberFormatter but the code does'nt work and i dont know why
here is the code

```
NSNumber* lat = [[NSNumber alloc]   initWithDouble:self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:8];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];
NSString *latit = [lat stringValue];
NSNumber *lati= [formatter numberFromString:(latit)];
NSLog(@"lat %@", lat);
NSLog(@"lati %@", lati);
```

I tried a lot of things as you can see converting to string etc. my console shows both lat lati to be the same.

Comment: If it's geolocation information, I'm sure you don't want to truncate the decimal places. Or would you like to end up in the nearby cemetery instead of your grandma's house?

Comment: hahaha, all i use the 'formated' lat is to display on the screen but to use with the map thing i use the real latitude.

Comment: Sorry for the nitpicking, I'm just curious: don't you think that that's misleading?

Comment: You display less precise data to the user than that is actually used. If he trusts your app and enters the coordinates to a GPS device, for example, he might very well end up in that particular cemetery...

Comment: ohh that, my client has specifically asked for this and we have informed them that the resulting data cannot be used out of this app and they are ok with it. the digits were taking to much space on the screen :)

Comment: @ChalamphonPandey In this case, that's OK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSNumber* lat = [[NSNumber alloc]  initWithDouble:self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:8];

[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromNumber:lat];
NSLog(@"lat %@", result);
```

Comment: @ChalamphongPandey Because if it's a math problem, you should use numbers only. The string representation of a number is never to be trusted, let alone relied upon.